# System crashes and reboots while using drag and drop

Tags: android, android-imageview, ontouchlistener

I have a layout where 4 image view will be there. 3 image view will have the image of ball,cat and apple image. I need to drag any 1 of the 3 and drop in the 4th image view.

**Issue :** 
When I start drag any one of the 3 image the system crashes and reboots. Could you please guide me to resolve this issue ?

### Java code:

```
package com.example.draganddrop;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ClipData; 
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.DragShadowBuilder;
import android.view.View.OnDragListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView; 
import android.widget.Toast;


@TargetApi(11)
public class DragDropActivity extends Activity {

//text views being dragged and dropped onto
private ImageView option1, option2, option3, choice1;
String type;

@TargetApi(11)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drag_drop);

    //get both sets of text views

    //views to drag
    option1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.option_1);
    option2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.option_2);
    option3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.option_3);

    //views to drop onto
    choice1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.choice_1); 

    //set touch listeners
    option1.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener( "ball"));
    option2.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener( "cat"));
    option3.setOnTouchListener(new ChoiceTouchListener( "apple" ));

    //set drag listeners
    choice1.setOnDragListener(new ChoiceDragListener(type)); 
}

/**
 * ChoiceTouchListener will handle touch events on draggable views
 *
 */
private final class ChoiceTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    ChoiceTouchListener(String typePassed){
        type = typePassed;
    }
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) { 

            switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.option_1: 
                Log.i("DragDropActivity"," 1. constructor dragging " + "ball" ); 
                break;  

            case R.id.option_2:  
                Log.i("DragDropActivity"," 2. constructor dragging " + "cat" );  
                break; 
            case R.id.option_3:  
                Log.i("DragDropActivity"," 3. constructor dragging " + "apple" );  
                break; 
            }

            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view); 
            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
} 

/**
 * DragListener will handle dragged views being dropped on the drop area
 * - only the drop action will have processing added to it as we are not
 * - amending the default behavior for other parts of the drag process
 *
 */
private class ChoiceDragListener implements OnDragListener {

    ChoiceDragListener(String type){ 
        Log.i("DragDropActivity"," constructor dragging " + type );  
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        View view = (View) event.getLocalState(); 
        switch (event.getAction()) { 
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED: 
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED: 
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:    
            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP: 
            Log.i("DragDropActivity"," Image is : dropped   " );  

            break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:  
            break;
        default:

            break;
        }

        return true;
    }
} 
    }
```

### LogCat of my Device

```
02-14 11:05:35.329: W/WindowManager(272): Drag is in progress but there is no drag window handle.
02-14 11:05:35.449: I/DragDropActivity(1259):  1. constructor dragging ball
02-14 11:05:35.469: I/DragDropActivity(1259):  dragging apple
02-14 11:05:35.469: I/DragDropActivity(1259):  Image started dragging 
02-14 11:05:35.579: I/DragDropActivity(1259):  Image is : dropped   
02-14 11:05:35.579: I/ViewRootImpl(1259): Reporting drop result: true
02-14 11:05:35.579: W/WindowManager(272): Drag is in progress but there is no drag window handle.
02-14 11:05:35.689: I/DragDropActivity(1259):  1. constructor dragging ball
02-14 11:05:35.709: I/DragDropActivity(1259):  dragging apple
02-14 11:05:35.709: I/DragDropActivity(1259):  Image started dragging 
02-14 11:05:35.819: I/DragDropActivity(1259):  Image is : dropped   
02-14 11:05:35.819: I/ViewRootImpl(1259): Reporting drop result: true
02-14 11:05:37.969: D/dalvikvm(658): GC_CONCURRENT freed 316K, 10% free 6751K/7495K, paused 2ms+2ms
02-14 11:05:38.069: D/dalvikvm(658): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 391K, 11% free 6712K/7495K, paused 16ms
02-14 11:05:41.689: D/lights(272): set_light_buttons: brightness=0
02-14 11:05:45.249: D/dalvikvm(658): GC_CONCURRENT freed 493K, 12% free 6669K/7495K, paused 5ms+3ms
02-14 11:05:52.509: D/dalvikvm(658): GC_CONCURRENT freed 470K, 11% free 6693K/7495K, paused 5ms+3ms
02-14 11:05:59.729: D/dalvikvm(658): GC_CONCURRENT freed 310K, 9% free 6870K/7495K, paused 2ms+2ms
02-14 11:05:59.809: D/dalvikvm(658): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 384K, 11% free 6712K/7495K, paused 15ms
02-14 11:06:06.989: D/dalvikvm(658): GC_CONCURRENT freed 487K, 12% free 6653K/7495K, paused 1ms+2ms
02-14 11:06:07.149: D/dalvikvm(489): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 750K, 12% free 9190K/10439K, paused 22ms
02-14 11:06:07.229: D/dalvikvm(658): GC_CONCURRENT freed 354K, 11% free 6701K/7495K, paused 2ms+3ms
02-14 11:06:10.009: W/ActivityManager(272): Timeout of broadcast BroadcastRecord{2bff8c10 android.intent.action.TIME_TICK} - receiver=android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$InnerReceiver@2bfb0bb8, started 10008ms ago
02-14 11:06:10.009: W/ActivityManager(272): Receiver during timeout: BroadcastFilter{2bfb0dc0 ReceiverList{2bfb0d48 272 system/1000 local:2bfb0bb8}}
02-14 11:06:15.380: I/3gw.Service(1245): Mobile Network not connected - not roaming
02-14 11:06:19.159: I/Process(272): Sending signal. PID: 272 SIG: 3
02-14 11:06:19.159: I/dalvikvm(272): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
02-14 11:06:19.199: I/dalvikvm(272): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-14 11:06:20.019: W/ActivityManager(272): Timeout of broadcast BroadcastRecord{2bff8c10 android.intent.action.TIME_TICK} - receiver=android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$InnerReceiver@2bf1fbd0, started 10008ms ago
02-14 11:06:20.019: W/ActivityManager(272): Receiver during timeout: BroadcastFilter{2bf33818 ReceiverList{2bf42f58 272 system/1000 local:2bf1fbd0}}
02-14 11:06:21.479: D/dalvikvm(658): GC_CONCURRENT freed 414K, 11% free 6725K/7495K, paused 2ms+4ms
02-14 11:06:21.589: D/dalvikvm(658): GC_CONCURRENT freed 394K, 11% free 6720K/7495K, paused 2ms+3ms 
02-14 11:06:28.799: D/lights(272): set_light_backlight: brightness=102
02-14 11:06:28.799: D/dalvikvm(658): GC_CONCURRENT freed 497K, 11% free 6673K/7495K, paused 2ms+3ms
02-14 11:06:28.819: D/lights(272): set_light_backlight: brightness=96
02-14 11:06:29.039: D/lights(272): set_light_backlight: brightness=26
02-14 11:06:29.059: D/lights(272): set_light_backlight: brightness=20
02-14 11:06:35.931: D/lights(272): set_light_backlight: brightness=0
02-14 11:06:35.931: I/power(272): *** set_screen_state 0
02-14 11:06:35.939: D/DASH - select(272): sensors_select_callback: select canceled by request
02-14 11:06:35.939: D/DASH - select(272): sensors_select_callback: select canceled by request
02-14 11:06:35.939: D/DASH-bma250_input(272): bma250_input_config_delay: rate:66667000
02-14 11:06:35.949: D/kernel(135): [  255.657379] request_suspend_state: sleep (0->3) at 251806856750 (2013-02-14 05:36:35.936248755 UTC)
02-14 11:06:35.949: D/kernel(135): [  255.657470] as3676 0-0040: as3676_early_suspend
02-14 11:06:35.949: D/kernel(135): [  255.661346] cyttsp-spi spi0.0: cyttsp_suspend: Enter
02-14 11:06:35.969: D/SurfaceFlinger(126): About to give-up screen, flinger = 0xfc48
02-14 11:06:36.089: D/dalvikvm(658): GC_CONCURRENT freed 472K, 11% free 6698K/7495K, paused 6ms+3ms
02-14 11:06:36.389: D/kernel(135): [  256.102478] active wake lock PowerManagerService
02-14 11:06:36.389: D/kernel(135): [  256.102539] active wake lock usb_bus_active
02-14 11:06:36.389: D/kernel(135): [  256.102569] active wake lock msm_otg
02-14 11:06:36.389: D/kernel(135): [  256.102600] active wake lock bq24185_watchdog_lock
02-14 11:06:36.389: D/kernel(135): [  256.102661] wake lock mmc_delayed_work, expired
02-14 11:06:49.205: W/Watchdog(272): WATCHDOG PROBLEM IN SYSTEM SERVER: com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService
02-14 11:06:49.209: I/Process(272): Sending signal. PID: 272 SIG: 3
02-14 11:06:49.209: I/dalvikvm(272): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
02-14 11:06:49.249: I/dalvikvm(272): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-14 11:06:49.249: I/Process(272): Sending signal. PID: 459 SIG: 3
02-14 11:06:49.249: I/dalvikvm(459): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
02-14 11:06:49.259: I/dalvikvm(459): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-14 11:06:51.265: I/Watchdog_N(272): dumpKernelStacks
02-14 11:06:51.265: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 272 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.265: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 274 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 277 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 278 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 279 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 280 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 281 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 282 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 283 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 288 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 289 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 291 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 292 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 293 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 294 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 296 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 297 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 298 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 299 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 300 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 302 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 303 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 304 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 305 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 306 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 307 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 308 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 309 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 310 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 312 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 313 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 314 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 316 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 317 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 318 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 327 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 328 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 329 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 330 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 331 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 332 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.269: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 333 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.279: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 334 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.279: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 335 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.279: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 336 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.279: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 337 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 338 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 339 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 340 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 341 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 342 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 343 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 352 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 353 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 359 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 362 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 363 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 415 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 417 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 430 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 450 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 452 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 455 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 457 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 475 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 488 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 490 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 494 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 511 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 547 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 588 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 590 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 592 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 597 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 598 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 623 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 624 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 767 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 881 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 882 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 883 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 884 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 969 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.289: E/Watchdog_N(272): Unable to open stack of tid 1352 : 13 (Permission denied)
02-14 11:06:51.369: D/dalvikvm(272): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1407K, 17% free 12077K/14471K, paused 70ms
02-14 11:06:53.297: I/Process(272): Sending signal. PID: 272 SIG: 9
02-14 11:06:53.297: W/Watchdog(272): *** WATCHDOG KILLING SYSTEM PROCESS: com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService
02-14 11:06:53.319: E/ViewRootImpl(1259): Unable to report drop result
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'content' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'netpolicy' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'power' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'bluetooth_a2dp' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'entropy' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'telephony.registry' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'cpuinfo' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'gfxinfo' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'account' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'textservices' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'statusbar' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'input_method' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'notification' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'devicestoragemonitor' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'accessibility' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'activity' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'permission' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'meminfo' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'network_management' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'netstats' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'clipboard' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'connectivity' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'wifi' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'mount' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'throttle' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'batteryinfo' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'usagestats' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'sensorservice' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'wifip2p' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'package' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'bluetooth' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'audio' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'usb' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'uimode' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'backup' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'appwidget' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'diskstats' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'samplingprofiler' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'search' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'dropbox' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'wallpaper' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'location' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'country_detector' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'hardware' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'vibrator' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'battery' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'alarm' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'device_policy' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ServiceManager(121): service 'window' died
02-14 11:06:53.319: W/AudioFlinger(143): power manager service died !!!
02-14 11:06:53.319: W/Sensors(1168): sensorservice died [0x165178]
02-14 11:06:53.319: W/Sensors(489): sensorservice died [0x204e88]
02-14 11:06:53.319: W/Sensors(459): sensorservice died [0x184328]
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ActivityThread(1562): Removing dead content provider: settings
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ActivityThread(1543): Removing dead content provider: settings
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ActivityThread(1522): Removing dead content provider: settings
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ActivityThread(1449): Removing dead content provider: settings
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ActivityThread(1168): Removing dead content provider: settings
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ActivityThread(1245): Removing dead content provider: settings
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ActivityThread(489): Removing dead content provider: settings
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ActivityThread(1099): Removing dead content provider: settings
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ActivityThread(658): Removing dead content provider: settings
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ActivityThread(418): Removing dead content provider: settings
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ActivityThread(459): Removing dead content provider: settings
02-14 11:06:53.319: I/ActivityThread(443): Removing dead content provider: settings
02-14 11:06:53.329: D/kernel(135): [  273.043487] binder: release 272:283 transaction 34753 in, still active
02-14 11:06:53.329: D/kernel(135): [  273.043518] binder: send failed reply for transaction 34753 to 658:1079
02-14 11:06:53.329: D/kernel(135): [  273.043548] binder: release 272:884 transaction 34264 in, still active
02-14 11:06:53.329: D/kernel(135): [  273.043548] binder: send failed reply for transaction 34264 to 1259:1259
02-14 11:06:53.329: I/ActivityThread(349): Removing dead content provider: settings
02-14 11:06:53.389: E/installd(130): eof
02-14 11:06:53.389: E/installd(130): failed to read size
02-14 11:06:53.389: I/installd(130): closing connection
02-14 11:06:53.419: D/kernel(135): [  273.138488] binder: 658:1079 transaction failed 29189, size 64-0
02-14 11:06:53.429: D/kernel(135): [  273.145935] alarm_release: clear alarm, pending 0
02-14 11:06:53.429: D/kernel(135): [  273.145965] alarm_release: clear alarm, pending 0
02-14 11:06:53.429: D/kernel(135): [  273.145965] alarm_release: clear alarm, pending 0
02-14 11:06:53.429: D/kernel(135): [  273.145965] alarm_release: clear alarm, pending 0
02-14 11:06:53.449: W/Display(658): Unable to get display size
02-14 11:06:53.449: W/Display(658): android.os.DeadObjectException
02-14 11:06:53.449: W/Display(658): 
02-14 11:06:53.449: W/Display(658): 
02-14 11:06:53.449: W/Display(658): 
02-14 11:06:53.449: W/Display(658): 
02-14 11:06:53.449: W/Display(658): 
02-14 11:06:53.449: W/Display(658): 
02-14 11:06:53.449: W/Display(658): 
02-14 11:06:53.449: W/Display(658): 
02-14 11:06:53.449: D/libEGL(1741): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
02-14 11:06:53.459: D/libEGL(1741): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
02-14 11:06:53.459: D/libEGL(1741): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
02-14 11:06:53.459: D/libEGL(1741): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
02-14 11:06:53.469: W/Display(658): Unable to get display size
02-14 11:06:53.469: W/Display(658): android.os.DeadObjectException
02-14 11:06:53.469: W/Display(658): 
02-14 11:06:53.469: W/Display(658): 
02-14 11:06:53.469: W/Display(658): 
02-14 11:06:53.469: W/Display(658): 
02-14 11:06:53.469: W/Display(658): 
02-14 11:06:53.469: W/Display(658): 
02-14 11:06:53.469: W/Display(658): 
02-14 11:06:53.469: W/Display(658): 
02-14 11:06:53.469: W/Display(658): 
02-14 11:06:53.499: W/dalvikvm(658): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2b542210)
02-14 11:06:53.519: E/InputQueue-JNI(489): channel '2bf9eb68 com.sonyericsson.home/com.sonyericsson.home.HomeActivity (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
02-14 11:06:53.529: D/kernel(135): [  273.240631] device rmnet0 left promiscuous mode
02-14 11:06:53.539: E/InputQueue-JNI(349): channel '2bf685c0 com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
02-14 11:06:53.549: E/InputQueue-JNI(349): channel '2c070728 StatusBar (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
02-14 11:06:53.559: E/AndroidRuntime(658): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-55
02-14 11:06:53.559: E/AndroidRuntime(658): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-14 11:06:53.559: E/AndroidRuntime(658): 
02-14 11:06:53.559: E/AndroidRuntime(658): 
02-14 11:06:53.559: E/AndroidRuntime(658): 
02-14 11:06:53.559: E/AndroidRuntime(658): 
02-14 11:06:53.559: E/AndroidRuntime(658): 
02-14 11:06:53.559: E/AndroidRuntime(658): 
02-14 11:06:53.559: E/AndroidRuntime(658): 
02-14 11:06:53.559: E/AndroidRuntime(658): 
02-14 11:06:53.559: D/BootAnimation(1741): persist.sys.boot.sound.volume:26
02-14 11:06:53.559: I/BootAnimation(1741): mp3 is null
02-14 11:06:53.599: E/InputQueue-JNI(349): channel '2c0aaec8 StatusBarExpanded (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
02-14 11:06:53.599: E/InputQueue-JNI(349): channel '2bfbbce8 TrackingView (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
02-14 11:06:53.599: E/InputQueue-JNI(1259): channel '2c0182b0 com.example.draganddrop/com.example.draganddrop.DragDropActivity (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
02-14 11:06:53.609: E/InputQueue-JNI(349): channel '2bfee2d0 RecentsPanel (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
02-14 11:06:53.609: E/InputQueue-JNI(459): channel '2c0ae360 com.android.phone/com.android.phone.SemcInCallScreen (client)' ~ Publisher closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
02-14 11:06:53.609: I/Zygote(127): Exit zygote because system server (272) has terminated
02-14 11:06:53.609: E/AndroidRuntime(658): Error reporting crash
02-14 11:06:53.609: E/AndroidRuntime(658): android.os.DeadObjectException
02-14 11:06:53.609: E/AndroidRuntime(658): 
02-14 11:06:53.609: E/AndroidRuntime(658): 
02-14 11:06:53.609: E/AndroidRuntime(658): 
02-14 11:06:53.609: E/AndroidRuntime(658): 
02-14 11:06:53.609: E/AndroidRuntime(658): 
02-14 11:06:53.619: I/Process(658): Sending signal. PID: 658 SIG: 9
: E/(): Device disconnected
```

Comment: _"system crashes and reboots"_ That does not sound right at all, can you get *any* logcat trace? This might also not be your code's issue, but instead a buggy OS.

Comment: Please post your error of the logcat.

Comment: logcat added. please check above

Comment: @user1822729 You ever figure this one out?

Comment: What device are you using?

Answer (score 0):

the reason is that: your screen upload action_move too lazily.

in normal case , action move is uploading very frequently even if your finger don't move on the screen. but some phone screens are not so sensitive.

you can modify the threshold of your  phone. It needs kernel support.

Answer (score 0):

this happened after action_drop

when the drop occur, windowmanager will unregister the input channel  that registered at the time of drag started.

the error is that unregisterInputChannel fail to get the lock and suspend.
this is a deadlock.

after about 30s passed, watchdog will kill the system_server to reboot android java world.